# Calculate free space remaining in JavaFX VBox

Tags: java, javafx, vbox

I'm creating a kiosk style application which displays custom `ScheduleItem` components (extends BorderPane) in a VBox.

I plan to provide the controller with a `List<ScheduleItem> fullSchedule` which it will use to populate the VBox.

What I need to do is check that the next item will fit in the remaining free space of the VBox before I add it, and if not, remember the position in the list and start from there when the scene is refreshed.

This will potentially run on both landscape and portrait screens, so I need a way to dynamically calculate the number of possible events per page.

The `ScheduleItem` components differ slightly in height depending on content of each item, so ideally the calculation will be performed for each item to be added.

This would throw a spanner in the works for my pagination system being able to calculate total number of pages based on total number of events. If one page displays 5 events, and another displays 4 etc.

The user does not interact, but ideally i'll be able to display the current page number and total number of pages.

I haven't yet looked into any type of pagination, so if this is something that is better handled by the Pagination system, please let me know and I'll remove this question. I haven't been able to find anything related in my searches, other than trying to fill the remaining empty space. I'd just like to calculate it.

**Note:** I've previously managed this in a PHP/JS application by populating a hidden container and comparing its size to the target container's size. If it exceeds the maximum visible height, don't add the event. I was hoping there might be a simple way with Java FX, as this is difficult to integrate with the pagination system.

Cheers!

Comment: Why not put your VBox in a ScrollPane? That way you can add as many items as you like.

Comment: Being a Kiosk view there is no user interaction. I could animate the scroll but I was hoping to display N amounts of events per page, before a timer pulls the next page. A scrollpane might be my best option though, cheers!

Comment: A custom ListView my be the best option here. Also JavaFx does have [Pagination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Pagination.html).